# Meaning of "You can see where he'd have trouble"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Rachel: C'mon Daddy, listen to me! It's like, it's like, all of my life, everyone has always told me, 'You're a shoe! You're a shoe, you're a shoe, you're a shoe!'. And today I just stopped and I said, 'What if I don't wanna be a shoe? What if I wanna be a- a purse, y'know? Or a- or a hat! No, I'm not saying I want you to buy me a hat, I'm saying I am a ha- It's a metaphor, Daddy!
>
> Ross: **You can see where he'd have trouble**

Answer (score 0):

This is from an [episode](https://www.bustle.com/p/the-rachel-centric-friends-episode-no-one-appreciates-enough-2934151) of "Friends". Ross is saying that Rachel's dad would have trouble understanding the metaphor she is using, just as Ross himself presumably doesn't quite get it.

Comment: Why he used "would have"?                                        He could have said "you can see where he has trouble"

Comment: It's a conditional - you can imagine this sentence being: he **would** have trouble **if** he tried to understand your metaphor. Maybe Ross doesn't think Rachel's father will even try to understand her. Either way it's a valid choice.

Comment: @SagarTamang If you find an answer helpful, instead of writing a "thank you" comment, you should upvote and/or accept it. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Rachel's parents were greedy. They only understood the value of money. Love was valueless and meaningless to them. They had also married only for money. So, they wanted to marry Rachel to a rich doctor named Barry against Rachel's wish. 
Rachel told her father on the phone that everyone thought her to be a shoe ; but she didn't want to be a shoe, she wanted to be a hat. She meant that she was willing to be independent in her decision, but unfortunately her father failed to understand the meaning of her metaphor. He said that he would buy her a hat. Ross, therefore, said that if Rachel's father could not understand the meaning of a simple metaphor, he would have trouble to understand her decision not to marry a doctor.

Comment: I know the context but I want to know why "would" is used.                                                         He could have said "you can see where he has trouble" or "where he may have trouble"